# ZF2 tree routing

Tags: php, zend-framework2, content-management-system

How to configure ZF2 tree pages routing?

I have multilevel pages. For example:

```
contacts
contacts/office
contacts/office/office1
products
products/category1
products/category1/product1
```

and more.

I use one controller for page and this config for routing:

```
'page' => array(
    'type'          => 'Literal',
    'options'       => array(
        'route'    => '/',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Application\PageController'
        )
    ),
    'priority'      => -1000,
    'may_terminate' => false,
    'child_routes'  => array(
        'name'   => array(
            'type'    => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'       => ':sn1[/:sn2[/:sn3[/:sn4[/:sn5[/:sn6]]]]]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'sn1' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*',
                    'sn2' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*',
                    'sn3' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*',
                    'sn4' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*',
                    'sn5' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*',
                    'sn6' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*'
                ),
                'defaults'    => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\PageController',
                    'action'     => 'page'
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Page action:

```
    $params = array('sn1', 'sn2', 'sn3', 'sn4', 'sn5', 'sn6');
    $names = array();
    foreach ($params as $param) {
        if($this->params($param, NULL) === NULL) {
            break;
        } else {
            $names[] = $this->params($param, NULL);
        }
    }
    var_dump($names);
    $path = implode('/', $names);
    var_dump($path);
```

Result for http://example.com/contacts/office/office1:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'contacts' (length=8)
  1 => string 'office' (length=6)
  2 => string 'office1' (length=7)
string 'contacts/office/office1' (length=23)
```

**Are there any better way to implement?**